# How to redirect to record detail page on selecting pick list value

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, pagereference, selectlist

## Controller

```
public class picklistController14July {

    public string selectedItem{get;set;}
    public list<selectOption> getAccountRecs(){
        list<selectOption> aList = new list<selectOption>();
        for(account a : [select id , name from account order by name desc limit 10]){
            alist.add(new selectOption(a.Id, a.Name));
        }
        return alist;
    }
    public pageReference save(){
        pageReference ref = new pageReference('/'+selectedItem);
        return ref;
    }
}
```

## Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="picklistController14July" >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:form >
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedItem}" size="1" title="Account Records" >
                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!accountRecs}"  />
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Select" />
    </apex:form>       
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I am getting run time message saying

> URL no onger exists.    You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com.

Comment: because you are passing the name instead of id in the URL

Comment: how to pass id ? @SantanuBoral

Answer (score 1):

Following things to be noted:

- pass `rowIndex` to the controller based on selection using `actionSupport`
- based on the `rowIndex`, retrieve the value using `getValue()` method. which will return the Id of selected account.
- no need to use `Save` button for your requirement.

> Use `getValue()` method
>
> which returns the option value that is returned to the controller if a user selects the option.

```
<apex:page controller="picklistController14July" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                
                    <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}"  />
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedItem}" size="1" title="Account Records">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="values" action="{!passValueToController}">
                            <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="index"/>
                         </apex:actionSupport>
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!accountRecs}"/>
                         
                        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:outputText value="{!fieldValue}" id="values"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class picklistController14July {

    public string selectedItem{get;set;}
    public list<selectOption> aList {get;set;}
    public list<selectOption> getAccountRecs(){
        aList = new list<selectOption>();
        for(account a : [select id , name from account order by name desc limit 10]){
            alist.add(new selectOption(a.Id, a.Name));
        }
        return alist;
    }
   public String fieldValue {get; set;}
    public pageReference  passValueToController(){
        Integer rowNum = Integer.valueOf(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));
        fieldValue = alist.get(rowNum).getValue();
        pageReference ref = new pageReference('/'+fieldValue);
        ref.setRedirect(true);
        return ref;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be a little more specific

Comment: see my updated code which is running perfectly at my DE

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my visualforce page. I just put the page block section and command button in the same form and now it's working.